# How to change only part of the text in php?

Tags: php

I have a php code that searches for words from a database in a text and highlights them:

```
<?php
            if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
                $text = $_POST['search'];
                $text2 = preg_replace("#[[:punct:]]#", "", $text);
                $words = explode(" ", $text2);
                $count = count($words);
                for ($i=0; $i<$count-1; $i++){
                    $word = $words[$i];
                    $word = trim($word);
                    $word1 = $words[$i+1];
                    $word2 = $word . ' ' . $word1;
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM ta WHERE name = '$word2'";
                    $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query); 
                    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
                    $word3 = $row['name'];
                    if (!empty($word3)) {
                        $text2 = str_replace($word3, "<span style='color:rgb(252, 127, 3);' class='mytext'>$word3</span>", $text);
                    }
                }
                echo nl2br($text2);
            }
        ?>
```

**Problem**: it only highlights the last word found

The problem is this line of code:

```
$text2 = str_replace($word3, "<span style='color:rgb(252, 127, 3);' class='mytext'>$word3</span>", $text);
```

Words to search for: 'hi mom', 'Jim'

Text: Jim entered the room and said:'hi mom'

Expected output: **Jim** entered the room and said:'**hi mom**'

Actual output: Jim entered the room and said:'**hi mom**'

Comment: `str_replace` does in fact replace all instances of a given search string. Perhaps you are looking for `stri_replace` (to eliminate case sensitivity). Please provide a text example, word to replace, expected output, and actual output.

Comment: Also, insert obligatory SQL injection warning. Use prepared statements whenever you accept input from a user.

Comment: Convert $text2 to array

Answer (score 0):

If you echo with in the `if` it will `echo` all.

```
$word3 = $row['name'];
if (!empty($word3)) {
$text2 = str_replace($word3, "<span style='color:rgb(252, 127, 3);' class='mytext'>$word3</span>", $text);
echo nl2br($text2);
}
```

Also if you want to print outside the loop, you can use an array to save all instances of `$text2`, like following.

```
$text2 = str_replace($word3, "<span style='color:rgb(252, 127, 3);' class='mytext'>$word3</span>", $text);
$text2Arr[]= $text2;
```